# Rails stars reviews

Tags: ruby-on-rails, review

I wonder what's the simplest way to implement stars review in Rails

I tried to use the following [snippet](http://jsfiddle.net/anuradhabajpai/L5KPw/7/),

```
$('.rating span').click(function(){
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
})
```

however the problem is I don't know how to finish it, for example I didn't get how to fix the colored stars and where to save a value, more complicated when rendering review how to color stars based on review integer I have, preferably how to color partial star when I have non-integer review value.

If there are good gem or simple steps how to proceed with above snippet I would appreciate for a help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are willing to go for non-integer values as well. I will suggest you to use the plugin [raty](http://wbotelhos.com/raty). Its a very simple plugin and can be used to highlight based on a number.

for your problem to save in the database. You can send an ajax and get the field updated.

```
var score = save the current score;

$.ajax({
  type: 'post',
   url : 'url/you/want'
  data: { rating : score, id: id}
  success : function(){
    //do what you want
  }
})
```

according to the above ajax, the value will be posted to the action where the `url` points to and will be posted there.

Inside that method you can receive the parameter to save it.

```
def methodname
  if params[:rating]
    @movie = Movie.find(params[:id])
    @movie.update_attributes(:rating => params[:rating])
  end
end
```